# I'm applying to get a Masters with Transfer and Transient undergraduate semesters during undergrad

Tags: graduate-admissions, transfer-student

After graduating high school, I went to a private out-of-state University for one semester, and it wasn't a good fit (it was a very strict religious institution), and so after the first semester, I became a transient student at a local community college, where I took courses for three semesters.

After getting the required hours I needed to transfer, I enrolled into the flagship University in my state, and graduated from there after three more years with two bachelors degrees- one BA in a modern language, one in BBA in International Business.

During one summer semester, I enrolled in a joint program between the flagship University I was attending, and the University to which I am now applying, for a foreign language program.

There's no academic dishonesty or anything to hide from those earlier schools, but I wasn't sure what is relevant or necessary to include as a part of my academic history.

The application I'm using offers the following guidance: *"List each institution after secondary school, Including [University Name], that you have attended or are currently attending."*

Additionally, there is no description, or note field where I could offer further explanation.

So, with that as background, **here are my questions**:

**1)** Generally, should transfer students put their old institutions on their history, even if they seem to be irrelevant (courses transferred, and graduation from the new University)?

**2)** Should I put the first religious University as one semester, or three semesters, or not at all? (Technically, I took classes there only one semester, but I was technically enrolled for three.)

**3)** How should I represent the community college where I was a transient student?
Or, since all credits transferred, do I need to list this institution at all?

**4)** How should I represent the joint foreign language program I attended between the University I graduated from for both degrees, and the school to which I am now applying? There was no degree for the program, but did offer course credit.

Any and all thought or feedback is appreciated.

Comment: In the U.S., for example, your should list _all_ enrollments, and send _all_ transcripts.

Comment: So, Transient and Transfer-from school to be included, does that also include the foreign language joint program? I tend to think that if they at least see an attempt to represent that program, that they won't look down on me for their online form not being conducive for showing certain enrollment types.

Comment: Admissions committees in the U.S. are well aware that their on-line application set-ups, usually designed by people who have little to do with the actual process, and scant knowledge of it (!!!???), are clumsy and inaccurate. Sure, it's not good to completely mess up the on-line forms, but no one is surprised when there are awkwardnesses.

Comment: The irony here is that I'm a software developer by trade. :) Thanks for your advice.